# Can't remove div on load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fixed div that covers the screen when a page is loaded and I want it to be deleted when the page is finished loading. I have tried using removeChild on the parent node but it doesn't seem to be working.

The body tag:

```
<body onload="showPage()">
```

The script code (at the bottom of the code, under the ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPage() {
        var cover = document.getElementByID("pageCover");
        cover.parentNode.removeChild(cover);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's getElementById ... note, lower case d

```
var cover = document.getElementById("pageCover");
cover.remove();
```

there's another code hint there too

so, really you can do it in one line

```
document.getElementById("pageCover").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be getElementById

```
   function showPage() {
        var cover = document.getElementById("pageCover");
        cover.parentNode.removeChild(cover);
    }
```